# Can org-mode export both link and url in html or odt?

Tags: org-mode

If I have links of the form [[http://www.google.com/][Google]] or the like, can I get org-mode to export them to ODT or HTML such that the links work for the electronic versions of the files and the links are also visible to see when printed?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html):

- [12.5.4 Links in HTML export](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Links-in-HTML-export) - How links will be interpreted and formatted
- [12.8.5 Links in ODT export](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Links-in-ODT-export) - How links will be interpreted and formatted

Comment: I see the links, but I don't understand how to do what I want.  Let me be more specific.  I can enter [[http://www.google.com][Google]], and I can create the text "Google" that has a link to the URL when I export the file.  What I want to get is something like "Google (http://www.google.com/)", where the printed URL is also active.  Perhaps one can do that with the ATTR_HTML, but I don't know how, and that wouldn't work for the ODT export, right?